# Change column with different formats into dates

Tags: r, date

Would like to change a column of my data.frame into the date format in R.

The problem is that the format of the column is not consistent.

Most rows are in the format `"%Y-%m-%d"` and I can change them easily with the `as.Date()` function.
Few rows are in the format `"%Y/%d/%m"` and  can't change them with the `as.Date()` function but instead I get `NA`'s.

```
    input <- c("2019-01-22", "2019-04-17", "2019/27/05", "2019/13/05", "2019/15/06", "2019-07-30")

    Input:           Output:

    Dates            Dates

    2019-01-22       2019-01-22
    2019-04-17       2019-04-17
    2019/27/05       2019-27-05
    2019/13/05       2019-13-05
    2019/15/06       2019-15-06
    2019-07-30       2019-07-30
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, in which you have "%Y-%m-%d" and "%Y/%d/%m", you might to use as.Date including the format it has. So, for example:

`input <- c("2019-10-11", "2019/27/10", "2014-12-10")`

If you use:

`input2 <- ifelse(grepl("/",input), format(as.Date(input,"%Y/%d/%m"),"%Y-%m-%d"), input)`

then:

```
> input2
[1] "2019-10-11" "2019-10-27" "2014-12-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only these two formats you can substitute all the `/` for `-`:

Example:

```
input <- c("2019-10-11", "2019/10/12", "2014-10-13")
as.Date(gsub("/", "-", input), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2019-10-11" "2019-10-12" "2014-10-13"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(input)
#[1] "2019-10-11" "2019-10-12" "2014-10-13"
```

---

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(input)
```

#### data

```
input <- c("2019-10-11", "2019/10/12", "2014-10-13")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace `/` by `-` for just a few rows, I think the following code might be an efficiency way to do the replacement

```
output <- as.Date(input)
output[is.na(output)]<-as.Date(input[is.na(output)],format = "%Y/%d/%m")
```

such that

```
> output
[1] "2019-01-22" "2019-04-17" "2019-05-27" "2019-05-13" "2019-06-15" "2019-07-30"
```